# PowerPC GCC Print registers in assembly without % sign

Tags: gcc, assembly, cpu-registers, powerpc

On Matt Godbolt's [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) website, you can compile code using various pre-installed compilers.  When using `PowerPC gcc 4.8` the registers cannot be distinguished from immediates (for example `addi 11,31,16`).

However, when the `-mregnames` option is used, all registers are marked with `%r` followed by the register index. **How do I omit just the `%` sign to get `r1` instead of `%r1`?**

For example, [`void nop () {}` with gcc4.8 PowerPC `-O0 -mregnames`](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'void+nop+()+%7B%0A%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:45.171322069863066,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:ppcg48,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'0'),libs:!(),options:'-O0+-mregnames',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'PowerPC+gcc+4.8+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),k:54.82867793013693,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
nop():
    stwu %r1,-16(%r1)
    stw %r31,12(%r1)
    mr %r31,%r1
    addi %r11,%r31,16
    lwz %r31,-4(%r11)
    mr %r1,%r11
    blr
```

Comment: If you omit the `%` the registers may be confused with symbols :) Why do you want to do it? The manual doesn't seem to have a way to do this.

Comment: @Jester:
I'm used to reading assembly without them

Comment: If it's for your own personal reading, just doing a search and replace for `%r[0-9]+` could work, obviously.

Comment: @Jester: Yes but this seems cumbersome but thanks for that suggestion though if it's the best you can do

Comment: Pro tip: post assembly listings as *text*, instead of as images.

Comment: @CodyGray:
Yeah but in this case it wasn't that important to have it in text format

Comment: It is *always* important, especially to our users that are blind. Not to mention, it's *easier* to copy and paste text than insert a screenshot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When targeting PowerPC, you basically have two options for the syntax of assembly listings:

You can either use the IBM syntax (common on IBM assemblers), where the registers do not use any type of special prefix: they are just referred to with numbers. Yes, this makes it difficult to distinguish them from immediates.

Or, you can use Gnu/AT&T syntax, which always prefixes registers with `%` symbols (and an `r`, in this case). This not only makes it easier to distinguish between registers and immediates, but it also makes it possible to distinguish between integer registers (`%r?`) and floating-point registers (`%f?`).

There is no intermediate option, where you get the `r` (or `f`) prefix, but no leading `%`. If you need this, you can do like Jester suggested and post-process the output, using the regular expression `%r[0-9]+` for matching.

Comment: Note that `objdump` produces the "`r` prefix without `%` " format by default. Trying to figure out how to make `gcc` produce that format is what brought me here, but the `%r` prefix is just as good for my purposes.

Answer (score 3):

An update:
powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc version 5.4.0 (the default package with Ubuntu 16.04)

When using -mregnames, you can use "%r0" or "r0" or "0" format for a register name in assembly source code files.

For disassembling, powerpc-linux-gnu-objdump defaults to the "r0" format (which I agree is easier to read).

In the example from that webpage, it looks like it is showing the listing output from the compiler, instead of using objdump. I do not know of a way to control the listing output format.